# Is my mixture too rich?

Tags: sparkplugs, carburetor, lambda

I've been running this single cyl scooter with this plug to about 30K KM (~19K miles). Replaced it today and it seems a bit dark. Is the engine's mixutre too rich?[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKp3Y.jpg)
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fotos differ each in color. Try to capture the plug in natural light, without flash.

Unless the colors in the foto are totally wrong, there can't be much wrong with the engine. Seems to be a nice brown tip. The insulator is also brown, but not too much. No debris or other oddities.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you very much for replying. I went outside and took two more images.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, Martin ... looks like a used spark plug with some mileage on it ... nothing to see here ... move along ... :o)

Comment: @BlackNinja - The additional images, unfortunately, aren't of much help. The spark plug is going to look darker against a light background, so the plug looks hugely darker then they probably are. Seriously, Martin is spot on with his analysis.

Comment: Hi guys, yeah, I added two more pictures. You're definately right about the background thing. I took it against a darker background and now it looks sort of brownish, which definately seems better IMO.

Comment: Hi guys, yeah, I added two more pictures. You're definately right about the background thing. I took it against a darker background and now it looks sort of brownish, which definately seems better IMO.

Comment: @BlackNinja - spelling: `definitely`.

Comment: Why did I find all the different pictures of this spark plug walking the earth, pleasing?